# Degree 1 and orientation-preserving homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

When I read a text book, I encountered the sentence

> "The modular group of genus $n$ is the group of isotopy classes of degree $1$ self-homeomorphism of a closed oriented surface of genus $n$".

Is "degree $1$" equivalent to "orientation preserving homeomorphism"?

Comment: Which textbook is this from?  What page is it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no. Maps of degree 1 need not be self-homeomorphisms, since they can easily fail to be injective. Imagine taking a circle and looping a little piece of it over itself. This is isotopic to the identity, but is certainly not a self-homeomorphism.

Comment: Then can we say "degree 1"="orientation preserving"?

Comment: Recall that both orientation and degree can be defined using the top homology (with integral coefficients, say) of the $n$-manifold $M$ we are considering. An orientation of $M$ is a choice of generator of $H_n(M) = \mathbb Z$, while the degree of a map $f: M \rightarrow M$ is the induced action on top homology. EDIT: I've screwed some things up. Hold on...

Comment: Okay, it won't let me keep editing it. Continuing:
...A diffeomorphism $M \to M$ is orientation-preserving if it sends our choice of generator to itself. So any orientation-preserving diffeo is degree 1, but it only makes sense to talk about preserving orientation when we're talking about a diffeo.

Comment: @NKS I don't see why you need to take diffeo. The same definition works fine for a homeomorphism. A homeomorphism has degree $1$ or $-1$, and it is orientation preserving iff its degree is $1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've been spending a lot of time with smooth stuff lately so "diffeo" came out just out of habit.